# Windows 10 won't boot after install of Ubuntu - stuck on black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on an old Macbook Air. I first installed Windows 10 which went fine, and then I installed Ubuntu which also seemed to go well but now Windows 10 won't boot. Once I select that option in Grub I just see a black screen and nothing happens.

I tried running Boot-Repair using a live disk and here is the output:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YhKdbQYMbQ/ and/or https://pastebin.com/4ADDjuHp

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================
 
 => Lilo is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (3.61-4.03) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 
sda1: __________________________________________________________________________
 
    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi
 
sda2: __________________________________________________________________________
 
    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
 
sda3: __________________________________________________________________________
 
    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe
 
sda4: __________________________________________________________________________
 
    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        
 
sda5: __________________________________________________________________________
 
    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub
 
sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________
 
    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi
 
 
================================ 2 OS detected =================================
 
OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on sda5
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda3
 
============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================
 
CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604, bionic, x86_64)
 
 
===================================== UEFI =====================================
 
BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
 
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c3889d54-2a2b-4838-bfcf-82025f71141b,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,c3889d54-2a2b-4838-bfcf-82025f71141b,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0080* Mac OS X  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,c8bd186c-9563-4c08-b2bc-17ebcab815a6,0x1d250438,0x135f20)
Boot0082*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,332608e5-2a5b-4d0b-b54d-04c352487a38,0x1d250438,0x135f20)
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,d41377ea-b4a5-4061-85cd-731fd2070ab4,0x14746358,0x5000000)/File(\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)
 
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda1/Boot/bootx64.efi
85fa9d77b929ec4231aba29476574eb6   sda1/Boot/fbx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   sda1/Boot/mmx64.efi
fa1bf1a7f90a852abe0bdbd089b7f1b0   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
3ff213addd49e6515922de34952223ad   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
b8736f6dbf1baf951d389be5a519fb32   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
 
 
============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================
 
Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________
 
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
 
Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________
 
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda4    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
 
Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________
 
sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
 
Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________
 
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda4    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda5    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
 
fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________
 
Disk sda: 233.8 GiB, 251000193024 bytes, 490234752 sectors
Disk identifier: 732B2CBA-A0B8-4CA0-8466-E7635C1058CC
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda3     239616 121836172 121596557    58G Microsoft basic data
sda4  121837568 122879999   1042432   509M Windows recovery environment
sda5  122880000 490233855 367353856 175.2G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 956 MiB, 1002438656 bytes, 1957888 sectors
Disk identifier: D0F4F353-01FF-4534-8A77-B942867398D0
      Start     End Sectors  Size Type
sdb1   2048 1955839 1953792  954M Microsoft basic data
Disk zram0: 983.1 MiB, 1030836224 bytes, 251669 sectors
Disk zram1: 983.1 MiB, 1030836224 bytes, 251669 sectors
Disk zram2: 983.1 MiB, 1030836224 bytes, 251669 sectors
Disk zram3: 983.1 MiB, 1030836224 bytes, 251669 sectors
 
parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________
 
sda:251GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA APPLE SSD SM0256:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:62.4GB:62.3GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:62.4GB:62.9GB:534MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
5:62.9GB:251GB:188GB:ext4::;
sdb:1002MB:scsi:512:512:gpt:USB Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:1001MB:1000MB:fat32::msftdata;
zram3:1031MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1031MB:1031MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram1:1031MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1031MB:1031MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram2:1031MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1031MB:1031MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram0:1031MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1031MB:1031MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
 
blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________
 
NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                
├─sda1 vfat     2602-5B7D                            c3889d54-2a2b-4838-bfcf-82025f71141b          EFI system partition
├─sda2                                               09753254-cdc0-4e90-a663-d237011082c8          Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda3 ntfs     6E2E0E252E0DE6C5                     687a5e3a-ab98-4b94-927b-122fbc7fe0ba          Basic data partition
├─sda4 ntfs     004E6E5B4E6E4A0C                     a0818e84-cd05-4c03-ad65-d859337992b6          
└─sda5 ext4     8d660e4d-98ac-4acc-b501-4f362a79c800 02f0f109-61af-4eae-9d58-ca0948e5e7dc          
sdb                                                                                                
└─sdb1 vfat     6E9E-1B0F                            85612771-35ad-4c18-983b-a0cd510dae00 UNTITLED 
zram0                                                                                              
zram1                                                                                              
zram2                                                                                              
zram3                                                                                              
 
df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________
 
       Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1      65M  32% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda3    44.3G  24% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sda4    88.3M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
sda5   155.8G   4% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
sdb1        0 100% /cdrom
 
Mount options: __________________________________________________________________
 
sda1   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda3   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda4   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda5   rw,relatime
sdb1   ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
 
===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================
 
search.fs_uuid 8d660e4d-98ac-4acc-b501-4f362a79c800 root hd0,gpt5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
 
====================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================
 
Ubuntu   8d660e4d-98ac-4acc-b501-4f362a79c800
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-30-generic   8d660e4d-98ac-4acc-b501-4f362a79c800
Windows Boot Manager (on sda1)   osprober-efi-2602-5B7D
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
 
========================== sda5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================
 
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=8d660e4d-98ac-4acc-b501-4f362a79c800 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2602-5B7D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
 
======================= sda5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================
 
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
 
==================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================
 
           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 130.727306366 = 140.367376384  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 108.907909393 = 116.938977280  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 108.907909393 = 116.938977280  boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-30-generic                 1
 109.316402435 = 117.377593344  boot/initrd.img                                2
 109.316402435 = 117.377593344  boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-30-generic              2
 109.316402435 = 117.377593344  boot/initrd.img.old                            2
 
===================== sda5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================
 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18151 Aug 12  2021 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Aug 12  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Aug 12  2021 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Aug 12  2021 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Aug 12  2021 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Aug 12  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Aug 12  2021 41_custom
 
====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================
 
Boot-Repair-Disk session
Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)
 
==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================
 
           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 
=============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux ===============
 
 menu.c32                           :  not a COM32/COM32R module
 
 
======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================
 
Unknown BootLoader on sdb1
 
00000000  eb 58 90 42 53 44 20 20  34 2e 34 00 02 08 20 00  |.X.BSD  4.4... .|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  20 00 80 00 00 08 00 00  |........ .......|
00000020  00 d0 1d 00 71 07 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |....q...........|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 0f 1b 9e 6e 55  4e 54 49 54 4c 45 44 20  |..)...nUNTITLED |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 fa 31 c0 8e d0 bc  |  FAT32   .1....|
00000060  00 7c fb 8e d8 e8 00 00  5e 83 c6 19 bb 07 00 fc  |.|......^.......|
00000070  ac 84 c0 74 06 b4 0e cd  10 eb f5 30 e4 cd 16 cd  |...t.......0....|
00000080  19 0d 0a 4e 6f 6e 2d 73  79 73 74 65 6d 20 64 69  |...Non-system di|
00000090  73 6b 0d 0a 50 72 65 73  73 20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65  |sk..Press any ke|
000000a0  79 20 74 6f 20 72 65 62  6f 6f 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  |y to reboot.....|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
 
 
========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive ==========
 
sdc 
 
=============================== StdErr Messages ================================
 
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[52765]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 18723: /bin/bash
 
Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________
 
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sda5,
using the following options:        sda1/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-backups  
 
Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________
 
 
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS entry (sda1/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
 
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
```

Comment: What happens when you boot Windows directly?

Comment: When I restart the computer holding Alt, I only have one option named Windows. When I select it, I get the behavior described above.

Comment: You should open UEFI settings > Boot menu and change the boot order to Windows bootloader manager. That, however, will probably give the same results (but it's worth trying anyway). If it's the same then you have a Windows problem and you have to understand that if Windows doesn't boot directly it won't boot from Grub either, obviously. Then the problem becames an Windows problem and off-topic here. Get yourself Windows installation media of the same version and repair it, that's all.

Comment: If on the other hand, you are able to boot Windows through the boot menu, then you would have to fix your GRUB. You might want to start with adding a custom entry to your grub menu so that you can still access your Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using gdisk as described here:
https://superuser.com/a/508454

Once I cleared the hybrid MBR data, Windows was able to boot as expected from the Grub menu.